# How to force ionic slides to respect column width

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been teaching myself new versions of AngularJS and Ionic by building an application. Currently I have a page constructed using ionic rows and columns. I have a 50/50 column on the page that renders JSON data. The left column is a text table and the right column is images in the ionic slider.

Problem is that the ionic slider does NOT respect the column width and I'm not sure how to correct this (I'm not overly familar with flexbox css). Last time I used Ionic (v1), the ionic-slide-box element was not causing me this issue.

Here is the HTML template code that I am using:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{macroDetails.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header><h1>{{macroDetails.title}}</h1></ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-50>

          <table>
            <tr>
              <td width="20%"><strong>Sensitivity Rating</strong></td>
              <td width="80%">{{macroDetails.sensitivity}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Phylum</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.phylum}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Class</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.class}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Order</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.order}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Family</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.family}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Genera</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.genera}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Size</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.size}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Habitat</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.habitat}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Diet</strong></td>
              <td [innerHTML]="macroDetails.diet"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><strong>Features</strong></td>
              <td>{{macroDetails.features}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col col-50>
          <small class="slideinfo">Swipe to change the images</small>
          <ion-slides pager="true">
            <ion-slide *ngFor="let images of macroDetails.featured_image">
              <img src="../assets/imgs/specimens/{{images}}.jpg" />
            </ion-slide>
          </ion-slides>
        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
```

I've looked over the ionic forums and SO for solutions but haven't seen any yet. Just hoping that someone has come across this before and can recommend a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh this is all my own silly fault! Did not read the updated ionic documentation properly. Now noticed that the ionic grid columns are now based on a BS grid system:

i.e. should be using "col-6" instead of "col-50" to display 1/2 - 1/2 layout spread.